# What is the best way to keep data between actions in zend framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a form and it is subdivided in multiple steps, and i would like to know what is the best way to keep the data.

I'm using php with zend framework 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the data in a session. This would be true in any application.