# How to get post data after submitting form

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP and I am trying to get post data after my form has been submitted. The problem I have is that I can get the post data on my success.php page, but if I move away from that page and go to another I can no longer get the values. So my question is how can I get the post data on another page?

My form

```
<form name="message" method="post" action="success.php">
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"/>
<p>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"/>
<p>
Message:<br />
<textarea name="message" id="message" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

success.php

```
<?php
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
echo "Firstname: $firstname<br/>";
echo "Lastname: $lastname<br/>";
echo "Message $message";
?>
```

Comment: This is what [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) are for

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to keep data between actions in zend framework 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406480/what-is-the-best-way-to-keep-data-between-actions-in-zend-framework-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the values in a session after your form has been submitted in success.php.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['message'])) {
session_start();
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname']; 
$message = $_POST['message'];

// store session data
$_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
$_SESSION['lastname'] = $lastname;
$_SESSION['message'] = $message;
}
?>
```

And then to fetch the data on your other page you could then use.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();
}
if (isset($_SESSION['firstname']) &&($_SESSION['lastname']) &&($_SESSION['message'])){
$firstname = $_SESSION['firstname'];
$lastname = $_SESSION['lastname'];
$message = $_SESSION['message'];
echo $firstname;
echo $lastname;
echo $message;
}
?>
```

Comment: I've not -1'd you but I can only guess whoever did it, did so because where you retrieve the session vars you have the potential for undefined vars.

Comment: This actually works. However I have one other question, what if the user returns to the page where the form is, will they be able to change the values again by re-submitting the form? If so is there a way to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much putting the same answer but clarified:

You can store these values in the session array.

```
$_SESSION['example'] = "testone";
$_SESSION['exampletwo'] = "testtwo";
```

and then either check for specific variables or loop through your current ones:

```
$example;
if (isSet($_SESSION['example'])) {
    $example = $_SESSION['example'];
} else {
    $example = "default";
}
echo "example's content: $example";

echo "Session array contents:";
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";
echo "Session from for loop:"
for ($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name => $value";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

STORE VALUES IN SESSION

```
    <?php
session_start();
    $firstname = $_SESSION['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_SESSION['lastname'];
    $message = $_SESSION['message'];
    ?>
```